# Creating a Basic connector for Informatica Cloud

Tags: informatica-powercenter, informatica

i never worked on Informatica cloud.just saw the Architecture of the cloud How it works.Now i have to create a connector .can any one please give any link.How to create a very basic Connector in Informatica.i go through this tutorial https://community.informatica.com/docs/DOC-2662 but it is giving a code and give overview of the code.i was not able to run `ant test` command in it .it is showing Build fail. i was not able to figure out here is the stack trace when i run ant test command

```
Buildfile: C:\Informatica\Informatic_FileIO_Connector\build.xml
[echoproperties] #Ant properties
[echoproperties] #Fri Mar 22 16:52:43 IST 2013
[echoproperties] ant.core.lib=C\:\\Ant\\apache-ant-1.9.0\\lib\\ant.jar
[echoproperties] ant.file=C\:\\Informatica\\Informatic_FileIO_Connector\\build
ml
[echoproperties] ant.file.Informatica_FileIO_Connector=C\:\\Informatica\\Infor
tic_FileIO_Connector\\build.xml
[echoproperties] ant.file.type=file
[echoproperties] ant.file.type.Informatica_FileIO_Connector=file
[echoproperties] ant.home=C\:\\Ant\\apache-ant-1.9.0
[echoproperties] ant.java.version=1.6
[echoproperties] ant.library.dir=C\:\\Ant\\apache-ant-1.9.0\\lib
[echoproperties] ant.project.default-target=package
[echoproperties] ant.project.name=Informatica_FileIO_Connector
[echoproperties] ant.version=Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.0 compiled on March 5
13
[echoproperties] awt.toolkit=sun.awt.windows.WToolkit
[echoproperties] basedir=C\:\\Informatica\\Informatic_FileIO_Connector
[echoproperties] connector.deploy.directory=C\:\\Users\\utsav\\Dropbox\\Deploy
nt\\CloudEvangelists\\fileio
[echoproperties] connector.plugin.class=com.ritesh.informatica.connector.impl.
leio.FileIOConnectorDescriptor
[echoproperties] connector.shortname=fileio
[echoproperties] connector.version=1.0.2
[echoproperties] debuglevel=source,lines,vars
[echoproperties] dir.bin.src=C\:\\Informatica\\Informatic_FileIO_Connector\\bi
\src
[echoproperties] dir.dist=C\:\\Informatica\\Informatic_FileIO_Connector\\dist
[echoproperties] dir.lib=C\:\\Informatica\\Informatic_FileIO_Connector\\lib
[echoproperties] dir.src=C\:\\Informatica\\Informatic_FileIO_Connector\\src
[echoproperties] env.\=C\:=C\:\\Informatica\\Informatic_FileIO_Connector
[echoproperties] env.\=ExitCode=00000000
[echoproperties] env.ALLUSERSPROFILE=C\:\\ProgramData
[echoproperties] env.ANT_CMD_LINE_ARGS=\ test
[echoproperties] env.ANT_HOME=C\:\\Ant\\apache-ant-1.9.0
[echoproperties] env.APPDATA=C\:\\Users\\utsav\\AppData\\Roaming
[echoproperties] env.Adobe_JAVA_HOME=C\:\\Adobe\\Adobe LiveCycle ES3\\Java\\jd
.6.0_26
[echoproperties] env.COMPUTERNAME=UTSAV-PC
[echoproperties] env.ComSpec=C\:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe
[echoproperties] env.CommonProgramFiles=C\:\\Program Files\\Common Files
[echoproperties] env.CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C\:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common
les
[echoproperties] env.CommonProgramW6432=C\:\\Program Files\\Common Files
[echoproperties] env.ERROR_CODE=0
[echoproperties] env.FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO
[echoproperties] env.HOME=C\:\\Users\\utsav
[echoproperties] env.HOMEDRIVE=C\:
[echoproperties] env.HOMEPATH=\\Users\\utsav
[echoproperties] env.JAVA_HOME=C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_43
[echoproperties] env.JAVA_HOME_32=C\:\\Adobe\\Adobe LiveCycle ES3\\Java\\32bit
jdk1.6.0_26
[echoproperties] env.LOCALAPPDATA=C\:\\Users\\utsav\\AppData\\Local
[echoproperties] env.LOGONSERVER=\\\\UTSAV-PC
[echoproperties] env.LenovoTestLogFile=preload.log
[echoproperties] env.LenovoTestPath=C\:\\prdv10\\
[echoproperties] env.MAVEN_HOME=C\:\\Maven\\apache-maven-3.0.5
[echoproperties] env.NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=4
[echoproperties] env.OS=Windows_NT
[echoproperties] env.PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;
SC
[echoproperties] env.PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
[echoproperties] env.PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7
GenuineIntel
[echoproperties] env.PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
[echoproperties] env.PROCESSOR_REVISION=2a07
[echoproperties] env.PROMPT=$P$G
[echoproperties] env.PSModulePath=C\:\\windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v
0\\Modules\\
[echoproperties] env.PUBLIC=C\:\\Users\\Public
[echoproperties] env.Path=C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_43\\bin;C\:\\Prog
m Files\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\Windows Live;C\:\\Program Files (x86)
Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\Windows Live;C\:\\windows\\system32;C\:\\windo
;C\:\\windows\\System32\\Wbem;C\:\\windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\
C\:\\Program Files\\Lenovo\\Bluetooth Software\\;C\:\\Program Files\\Lenovo\\B
etooth Software\\syswow64;C\:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Live\\Shared;C\:\\
encv\\build\\common\\tbb\\intel64\\vc10\\;C\:\\opencv\\build\\x64\\vc10\\bin\\
\:\\Ant\\apache-ant-1.9.0\\bin;C\:\\Maven\\apache-maven-3.0.5\\bin;
[echoproperties] env.ProgramData=C\:\\ProgramData
[echoproperties] env.ProgramFiles=C\:\\Program Files
[echoproperties] env.ProgramFiles(x86)=C\:\\Program Files (x86)
[echoproperties] env.ProgramW6432=C\:\\Program Files
[echoproperties] env.SESSIONNAME=Console
[echoproperties] env.SystemDrive=C\:
[echoproperties] env.SystemRoot=C\:\\windows
[echoproperties] env.TEMP=C\:\\Users\\utsav\\AppData\\Local\\Temp
[echoproperties] env.TMP=C\:\\Users\\utsav\\AppData\\Local\\Temp
[echoproperties] env.USERDOMAIN=utsav-PC
[echoproperties] env.USERNAME=utsav
[echoproperties] env.USERPROFILE=C\:\\Users\\utsav
[echoproperties] env.WB_JRE_HOME=C\:\\Adobe\\workbench\\jre
[echoproperties] env._JAVACMD=C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_43\\bin\\java
xe
[echoproperties] env._USE_CLASSPATH=no
[echoproperties] env.configsetroot=C\:\\windows\\ConfigSetRoot
[echoproperties] env.windir=C\:\\windows
[echoproperties] env.windows_tracing_flags=3
[echoproperties] env.windows_tracing_logfile=C\:\\BVTBin\\Tests\\installpackag
\csilogfile.log
[echoproperties] file.encoding=Cp1252
[echoproperties] file.encoding.pkg=sun.io
[echoproperties] file.separator=\\
[echoproperties] infa.junit=C\:\\Informatica\\Informatic_FileIO_Connector/INFA
Unit
[echoproperties] infaagent.directory=C\:\\Program Files (x86)\\Informatica Clo
 Secure Agent
[echoproperties] java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment
[echoproperties] java.awt.printerjob=sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob
[echoproperties] java.class.path=C\:\\Ant\\apache-ant-1.9.0\\lib\\ant-launcher
ar;C\:\\Ant\\apache-ant-1.9.0\\lib\\ant-antlr.jar;C\:\\Ant\\apache-ant-1.9.0\\
b\\ant-apache-bcel.jar;C\:\\Ant\\apache-ant-1.9.0\\lib\\ant-apache-bsf.jar;C\:
Ant\\apache-ant-1.9.0\\lib\\ant-apache-log4j.jar;C\:\\Ant\\apache-ant-1.9.0\\l
\\ant-apache-oro.jar;C\:\\Ant\\apache-ant-1.9.0\\lib\\ant-apache-regexp.jar;C\
\Ant\\apache-ant-1.9.0\\lib\\ant-apache-resolver.jar;C\:\\Ant\\apache-ant-1.9.
\lib\\ant-apache-xalan2.jar;C\:\\Ant\\apache-ant-1.9.0\\lib\\ant-commons-loggi
.jar;C\:\\Ant\\apache-ant-1.9.0\\lib\\ant-commons-net.jar;C\:\\Ant\\apache-ant
.9.0\\lib\\ant-jai.jar;C\:\\Ant\\apache-ant-1.9.0\\lib\\ant-javamail.jar;C\:\\
t\\apache-ant-1.9.0\\lib\\ant-jdepend.jar;C\:\\Ant\\apache-ant-1.9.0\\lib\\ant
mf.jar;C\:\\Ant\\apache-ant-1.9.0\\lib\\ant-jsch.jar;C\:\\Ant\\apache-ant-1.9.
\lib\\ant-junit.jar;C\:\\Ant\\apache-ant-1.9.0\\lib\\ant-junit4.jar;C\:\\Ant\\
ache-ant-1.9.0\\lib\\ant-launcher.jar;C\:\\Ant\\apache-ant-1.9.0\\lib\\ant-net
xx.jar;C\:\\Ant\\apache-ant-1.9.0\\lib\\ant-swing.jar;C\:\\Ant\\apache-ant-1.9
\\lib\\ant-testutil.jar;C\:\\Ant\\apache-ant-1.9.0\\lib\\ant.jar;C\:\\Program
les\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_43\\lib\\tools.jar
[echoproperties] java.class.version=50.0
[echoproperties] java.endorsed.dirs=C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_43\\jre
lib\\endorsed
[echoproperties] java.ext.dirs=C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_43\\jre\\lib
ext;C\:\\windows\\Sun\\Java\\lib\\ext
[echoproperties] java.home=C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_43\\jre
[echoproperties] java.io.tmpdir=C\:\\Users\\utsav\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\
[echoproperties] java.library.path=C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_43\\bin;
:\\windows\\Sun\\Java\\bin;C\:\\windows\\system32;C\:\\windows;C\:\\Program Fi
s\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_43\\bin;C\:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\
ndows Live;C\:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\Windows L
e;C\:\\windows\\system32;C\:\\windows;C\:\\windows\\System32\\Wbem;C\:\\window
\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C\:\\Program Files\\Lenovo\\Bluetooth Sof
are\\;C\:\\Program Files\\Lenovo\\Bluetooth Software\\syswow64;C\:\\Program Fi
s (x86)\\Windows Live\\Shared;C\:\\opencv\\build\\common\\tbb\\intel64\\vc10\\
\:\\opencv\\build\\x64\\vc10\\bin\\;C\:\\Ant\\apache-ant-1.9.0\\bin;C\:\\Maven
apache-maven-3.0.5\\bin;;.
[echoproperties] java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
[echoproperties] java.runtime.version=1.6.0_43-b01
[echoproperties] java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification
[echoproperties] java.specification.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
[echoproperties] java.specification.version=1.6
[echoproperties] java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
[echoproperties] java.vendor.url=http\://java.sun.com/
[echoproperties] java.vendor.url.bug=http\://java.sun.com/cgi-bin/bugreport.cg
[echoproperties] java.version=1.6.0_43
[echoproperties] java.vm.info=mixed mode
[echoproperties] java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
[echoproperties] java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification
[echoproperties] java.vm.specification.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
[echoproperties] java.vm.specification.version=1.0
[echoproperties] java.vm.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
[echoproperties] java.vm.version=20.14-b01
[echoproperties] line.separator=\r\n
[echoproperties] os.arch=amd64
[echoproperties] os.name=Windows 7
[echoproperties] os.version=6.1
[echoproperties] path.separator=;
[echoproperties] source=1.6
[echoproperties] sun.arch.data.model=64
[echoproperties] sun.boot.class.path=C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_43\\jr
\lib\\resources.jar;C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_43\\jre\\lib\\rt.jar;C\
\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_43\\jre\\lib\\sunrsasign.jar;C\:\\Program Files
Java\\jdk1.6.0_43\\jre\\lib\\jsse.jar;C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_43\\j
\\lib\\jce.jar;C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_43\\jre\\lib\\charsets.jar;C
\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_43\\jre\\lib\\modules\\jdk.boot.jar;C\:\\Progr
 Files\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_43\\jre\\classes
[echoproperties] sun.boot.library.path=C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_43\\
e\\bin
[echoproperties] sun.cpu.endian=little
[echoproperties] sun.cpu.isalist=amd64
[echoproperties] sun.desktop=windows
[echoproperties] sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle
[echoproperties] sun.java.command=org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher test
[echoproperties] sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD
[echoproperties] sun.jnu.encoding=Cp1252
[echoproperties] sun.management.compiler=HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
[echoproperties] sun.os.patch.level=Service Pack 1
[echoproperties] target=1.6
[echoproperties] user.country=US
[echoproperties] user.dir=C\:\\Informatica\\Informatic_FileIO_Connector
[echoproperties] user.home=C\:\\Users\\utsav
[echoproperties] user.language=en
[echoproperties] user.name=utsav
[echoproperties] user.timezone=
[echoproperties] user.variant=
[echoproperties] wsdl.location=C\:\\Informatica\\Informatic_FileIO_Connector\\
dl\\xyz.wsdl

clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Informatica\Informatic_FileIO_Connector\bin\
c
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Informatica\Informatic_FileIO_Connector\dist
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Informatica\Informatic_FileIO_Connector\INFA
Unit

init:
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Informatica\Informatic_FileIO_Connector\bin\src
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Informatica\Informatic_FileIO_Connector\dist
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Informatica\Informatic_FileIO_Connector\dist\Adapt
-jars

compile:
    [javac] C:\Informatica\Informatic_FileIO_Connector\build.xml:61: warning:
ncludeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to f
se for repeatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 4 source files to C:\Informatica\Informatic_FileIO_Conne
or\bin\src
    [javac] C:\Informatica\Informatic_FileIO_Connector\src\com\ritesh\informat
a\connector\impl\fileio\FileIOConnectorConstants.java
    [javac] C:\Informatica\Informatic_FileIO_Connector\src\com\ritesh\informat
a\connector\impl\fileio\FileIOConnectorDescriptor.java
    [javac] C:\Informatica\Informatic_FileIO_Connector\src\com\ritesh\informat
a\connector\impl\fileio\FileIOConnectorImpl.java
    [javac] C:\Informatica\Informatic_FileIO_Connector\src\com\ritesh\informat
a\connector\impl\fileio\util\FileIOUtils.java

createAdapterJar:
     [echo] Informatica_FileIO_Connector: C:\Informatica\Informatic_FileIO_Con
ctor\build.xml
      [jar] Building jar: C:\Informatica\Informatic_FileIO_Connector\dist\Adap
r-jars\fileio-adapter-1.0.2.jar

package:
     [copy] Copying 18 files to C:\Informatica\Informatic_FileIO_Connector\dis
Adapter-jars
      [zip] Building zip: C:\Informatica\Informatic_FileIO_Connector\dist\pack
e-fileio.ver.zip

test:
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\Informatica\Informatic_FileIO_Connector\Adap
r-jars
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Informatica\Informatic_FileIO_Connector\INFA_JUnit
unit_results
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Informatica\Informatic_FileIO_Connector\INFA_JUnit
unit_reports
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Informatica\Informatic_FileIO_Connector\Adapter-ja

     [copy] Copying 8 files to C:\Informatica\Informatic_FileIO_Connector\Adap
r-jars
    [junit] Running com.informatica.cloud.api.adapter.test.metadata.Registrati
InfoTest
    [junit] Tests run: 9, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.
 sec
    [junit] Running com.informatica.cloud.api.adapter.test.typesystem.DataType
stTest
    [junit] Tests run: 52, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0
65 sec
    [junit] Running com.informatica.cloud.api.adapter.test.typesystem.TypeSyst
Test
    [junit] Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.
2 sec
    [junit] Running com.informatica.cloud.api.adapter.test.plugin.PluginTest
    [junit] Tests run: 7, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.
9 sec

BUILD FAILED
C:\Informatica\Informatic_FileIO_Connector\build.xml:121: Tests failed

Total time: 4 seconds
```

i think in build.xml file there is a code segment

```
<!-- Deploy Directory should point to the dropbox folder for deployment -->
    <property name="connector.deploy.directory" location="C:\Users\pugupta\Dropbox\Deployment\CloudEvangelists\fileio" />
```

but i have no such folder on my machine what to put in this field.in workbook for this property description is 
**Optional: If Informatica has shared a deployment dropbox folder with you. Then change the value of connector.deploy.directory to point to your local dropbox folder for connector deployment (Informatica will share a dropbox folder with you for connector deployment)**

but i just signed up for developer org and i am not provided with any dropbox folder .what to put in this field so that my build successful.please some one help me in resolving this issue and a get start guide for creating a basic Connector?? please someone help so that i can proceed further.

Comment: @Marek sir please guideline how to create a connector in Informatica cloud!!

Comment: Unfortunately I have never worked with Informatica Cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Did you post this in Informatica cloud communities? The response there is usually faster there.